# Change the step value of figure colorbar in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a colorbar in a figure in Matlab. It ranges from 0 to 4. The colorbar appears like this: `0,0.5,1,1.5,2,1.5,2,2.5,3` so as shown the step value is `0.5`. I want it to step 1 at a time so that it appears like this: `0,1,2,3,4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following lines should do it:

```
hcb=colorbar;
set(hcb,'YTick',0:4);
```